Unable to create a windows 10 bootable usb on Ubuntu 24.04
I was able to use an app (cannot remember what it was) on 22.04 to make a windows 10 USB bootable disk but unable to find anything that works.

I've tried WoeUSB and cannot get it install for the life of me. No idea if that would even work but it's been a waste of time for me. Not sure what, or even if, I am doing something wrong.

The Disk utility actually seemed to work but at the end it just hangs right at the end.


Any other apps that work well for this? No idea who difficult it is to install Wine and use Rufus or even if its' worth it.

Not sure what Wine has to do with a Windows USB creation, but I found the wimsplit package offers the wimsplit tool to break up the one oversized file from the Windows ISO, so everything can fit on a USB formatted with a FAT filesystem. That worked for booting Windows for me. Use Windows Media Creation tool from Windows, it's easier, but insists on doing the ISO download as I recall.

You can use Ventoy

The "app" that I see as most useful for writing disk images is           (besides Linux dd)
Balena Etcher - which I believe is available for any and all OS:es.
Trying to access RAW disk content from within a emulated environment (e.g. Wine, cygwin, WSL, VM or Docker, ...) is often cumbersome or "special" in some way.
i.e. You might succeed if you know the emulated environment does it.
